# Error when run server rails 2.3.5 with memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use ruby version 1.8.7, gem version 1.3.5, rails version 2.3.5 and memcache. I get this error when I run server

```
phuongnm-lap:~/trunk/hurricane$ ruby script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require': /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/get_process_mem-0.2.0/lib/get_process_mem.rb:60: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<value>(\d*\.{0,1}\d+))\s+(?<unit>\w\w)/ (SyntaxError)
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:41:in `load_gems'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/config/environment.rb:34
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/asiantech/trunk/hurricane/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Your ruby version is **too old for the `get_process_mem` gem to run**. The gem uses a [complex regular expression](https://github.com/schneems/get_process_mem/blob/master/lib/get_process_mem.rb#L63) to parse information from `/proc` files on your linux server. However, ruby 1.8.7 does not support such complex regexp yet.

You can see for yourself in irb. In ruby 1.8.7 the match fails:

```
"aaa" =~ /(?<value>(\d*\.{0,1}\d+))\s+(?<unit>\w\w)/
# => SyntaxError: compile error
# => (irb):1: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<value>(\d*\.{0,1}\d+))\s+(?<unit>\w\w)/
```

whereas under ruby 2.2 it works ok (does not return anything in this test case, but more importantly, does not fail with error):

```
"aaa" =~ /(?<value>(\d*\.{0,1}\d+))\s+(?<unit>\w\w)/
# => nil
```

You have a few options now:

- Upgrade to a newer ruby (and rails) if you can, you won't have to solve these elderly code-related problems and won't be using an unsupported ruby/rails version any more, but nevertheless this is rather a cumbersome process.
- Get rid of the `get_process_mem` gem. You can see the same info, i.e. the memory consumed by the process, using command line utilities, without needing to install any gem. **Try the `top` or `htop` commands for example.**

Comment: Thank your reply. I understand my problem